# Formal or cartoon-like website

Tags: website-design, user-research

Think about two websites related to research work. One is:

http://www.tnsglobal.com/who-we-are

and the other is

http://www.conento.com.tr/EN/

I really wonder how many people like the first one (because it represents a serious work) and how many people like the second one (because it's different, non-cliche website).

Is there any study related to this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to convey to users. If your research work lies in a more serious business (medical, advanced physics, etc...) a more serious/formal site will convey a more respectable notion. Now, for the other hand, if you research UI, for example one geared for children, a more cartoon like can be more appealing and also convey the work you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Serious tool => serious style. I think at least some users may find the cartoon-like website as not serious (think about corpos, men in ties...). I wouldn't go cartoon style.